# Solve the differential equation $\frac{3y^2-t^2}{{y^5}}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{t}{2y^4}=0$, with initial condition $y(1)=1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $\dfrac{3y^2-t^2}{{y^5}}\dfrac{dy}{dt}+\dfrac{t}{2y^4}=0$, with initial condition $y(1)=1$.

I was doing some textbook problems from my textbook when I saw the question above, in the section for Exact Equations.

My attempt:

$\dfrac{3y^2-t^2}{{y^5}}\dfrac{dy}{dt}+\dfrac{t}{2y^4}=0\\\implies \dfrac{3y^2-t^2}{{y^5}}dy+\dfrac{t}{2y^4}dt=0$

Then I'd usually let the term in front of the $dx$ be $M(x,y)$ and the term in front of the $dt$ be $N(t,y)$. Then I'd find $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}$ and $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial t}$, and if they were equal, then I could conclude that they were exact equations. But in this case,  $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial t}$, so is there a way to make it exact?

I got:

$M(t,y)=\dfrac{3y^2-t^2}{y^5}=(3y^2-t^2)\cdot y^{-5}=3y^{-3}-t^2y^{-5}$

$N(t,y)=\dfrac{t}{2y^4}=2ty^{-4}$

$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{3y^{-4}}{4}+\dfrac{t^2y^{-6}}{6}$

$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial t}=-\dfrac{2ty^{-5}}{5}$, so  $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}\neq \dfrac{\partial N}{\partial t}$

Comment: Try to multiply the whole equation by some well-chosen function $f(y,t)$ which is never zero. It should hold that $(fM)_y=(fN)_t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets swap their names:

$M(t,y)=\dfrac{t}{2y^4}$

$N(t,y)=\dfrac{3y^2-t^2}{y^5}$

$\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{2t}{y^5}$

$\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial t}=-\dfrac{2t}{y^5}$

Comment: Thank you. It slipped my mind to check the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Use $y = vt$ this should reduce the equation to:
$$
\frac{3v^{2}-1}{v}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}vt + \frac{1}{2} = 0
$$
Which leads to 
$$
\left(\frac{3v^{2}-1}{v}\right)v + \left(\frac{3v^{2}-1}{v}\right)t\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} +\frac{1}{2} = 0.
$$
You should be able to rearrange for v and solve for y.